# Message sent to Deallocated Instance - in Singleton

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I see a lot of these questions asked with no answers... hopefully someone can help me out.

So I created a singleton in my app, and I reload a scene but then receive this message when I try to access data for my enemy paths.

Here's the code in the Singleton

In the init:

```
 NSString *resourcePath = @"EnemyPaths";
    NSString *levelDefsFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resourcePath ofType:@"plist"];
    _enemyPaths = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:levelDefsFile];
```

And when I reload the scene I call this function in the singleton to free up the old data

```
-(void) resetGameData
{
    [enemy1 release];
    [enemy2 release];
    [enemy3 release];
    [enemy4 release];
    [enemy5 release];
    [enemy6 release];
    [enemy7 release];
    [enemy8 release];
    [enemy9 release];
    [enemy10 release];

    [self setupEnemyPaths];
}

-(void) setupEnemyPaths
{
    NSString *getLevel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level%d", CURRENT_LEVEL];
    NSAssert(_enemyPaths != nil, @"Couldn't open EnemyPaths file");
    _level = (NSDictionary *) [_enemyPaths objectForKey:getLevel];
    NSAssert(_level != nil, @"Couldn't find Level entry");

...
}
```

I get the error on

```
_level = (NSDictionary *) [_enemyPaths objectForKey:getLevel];
```

but I'm not sure why- The _enemyPaths is alloc'd and I never released it.. or am I missing something? Please help!

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to have the NSAssert be this NSAssert(_enemyPaths == nil, @"Couldn't open EnemyPaths file");

Comment: ugh thank you im an idiot- ill update if i can figure out this issue now, edited.

Comment: errrrr actually when I set to == nil then it wont read the file, but its fine and reads the data as != nil

Comment: 10 vars for 10 enemies? You do know how to setup a dictionary, why not put the enemies into an array too?

Comment: hahah they're actually 10 arrays for enemy paths. Each array corresponds with the enemy. I changed the variables names when I posted it here because I thought I was cool :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I believe the items weren't being copied and were directly used, switched to copying each item and everything is fine. Must have ended up having an empty Dictionary on the call.